# Sorting array with NSSortDescriptor for specific item

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I am using an `NSSortDescriptor` to sort an array as follows:

```
NSSortDescriptor *titleDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: titleDescriptor, nil]; 

self.items = (NSMutableArray*)[self.items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Which works great. What I would like to do is have one specific "title" (from which I know the exact string) always at the top of the list, and then have the `NSSortDescriptor`'s sort the rest of the titles alphabetically below said title. What is the syntax to accomplish this using `NSSortDescriptor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use one of the other methods like `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` to gain this level of control.

Also, don't just cast the result to a mutable array. If the array is mutable, use the method which sorts the mutable array. If you use the method to create a new array, make sure it is mutable by calling `mutableCopy` on the result.